# Ngrok Bad Gateway Intermittent 502

Tags: apache, laravel, twilio, ngrok

I am running ngrok to forward webhooks at my local vagrant running ubuntu and apache (it is a php laravel application).  I am getting intermittent bad gateway errors.

What is strange is that the inspector on http://127.0.0.1:4040/ is showing 200's

The third party system that is firing the webhooks is returning the raw html as

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

    </body>
</html>
```

Because it works sometimes I don't think there is a problem with the setup. Any suggests would be helpful.  Right now I just hit it again and again until it is successful.

One thing is that the local dev is slow,

For example from the ngrok inspector.

> GET /inbound/webhook  200 OK  3.44s

I noticed that the slower response are more likely to throw a 502.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Given that's an nginx error page and you're running Apache, this seems like it might be a problem with ngrok itself. Might be worth opening an issue on the [ngrok GitHub project](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues).

Comment: There is a 15 second request timeout so it should not be a network performance issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So actually what is happening in your case is, the request is reaching your server and it responds after the request has been timed out. Hence Twilio responds with 502 after a timeout. But your server is sending a correct response (Request is not capable of taking your response due to delay).

Kindly make sure your server's responding time is faster! That will fix this.